# SizeLimitExceededException not catch when upload MultipartFile

Tags: grails, groovy

I want catch exception SizeLimitExceededException when i upload a big file.
However, i have created a method in controller to catch this exception but he return :

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/user/uploadProfileImage
Class
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload
.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException
Message
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload
.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (310380) exceeds the configured maximum (128000)
Caused by
the request was rejected because its size (310380) exceeds the configured maximum (128000)
```

Method to catch exception:

```
def handleSizeLimitExceededException(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException ex){
     render(['error':true, message:ex.getMessage()] as JSON)
}
```

My controller:

```
class UserController {
...
    def uploadProfileImage(ProfileImageCommand cmd) {
        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
                //respond(cmd, model: [user: cmd], view: 'create')
                response.status = 500
                render(['error':true, message:cmd.getErrors()] as JSON)
            }

        String filename = uploadFileService.uploadFileInTemp(cmd, relativePathTmp)

        Locale locale = request.locale
        //flash.message = crudMessageService.message(CRUD.UPDATE, domainName(locale), pointOfInterest.id, locale)
        render(['filename':filename, 'url': uploadFileService.getUrl(filename, relativePathTmp)] as JSON)
    }

    def handleSizeLimitExceededException(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException ex){
        render(['error':true, message:ex.getMessage()] as JSON)
    }
}
```

My Validateable:

```
class ProfileImageCommand implements Validateable {
    MultipartFile imageFile

    static constraints = {
        imageFile  validator: { val, obj ->
            if ( val == null ) {
                return false
            }
            if ( val.empty ) {
                return false
            }

            ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'].any { extension ->
                val.originalFilename?.toLowerCase()?.endsWith(extension)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: okay it's noted, I added error that I meet. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your grails version. I'm assuming its 3+

In application.yml, you can set the the maximum size of file you want to upload with these settings.

```
grails:
controllers:
        upload:
            maxFileSize: 20000000
            maxRequestSize: 20000000
```

This example sets both request and file size to 20MB. You can tune it to your needs.

Comment: I use Grails 3.8.8.
Yes i can increase the maximum but i want manage the errors of my web service

Comment: @Geek what do you mean by managing errors? Did you try the above solution? What was the outcome?

Comment: But what happens when the max file size is exceeded? How to catch that exception in Grails?